# Sysdate Oracle to Run Based on Day

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

This is probably an easy question for most of you but how can I get this mask to run based on just the day?

If anyone knows Crystal Reports syntax, we have this and it works {PO_RECEIPTS.DATE_RECEIVED} = currentdate

However, when converting to Oracle SQL, how can I the standard: TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') to become range so we can selected everything during the day, not just what matched the second in which the report was ran which it never will.

So something like Today from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PO_RECEIPTS.DATE_RECEIVED` is a date column where all the times are set to midnight then you can do:

```
WHERE PO_RECEIPTS.DATE_RECEIVED = TRUNC(sysdate)
```

If the values have other times then you can use a range:

```
WHERE PO_RECEIPTS.DATE_RECEIVED >= TRUNC(sysdate)
AND PO_RECEIPTS.DATE_RECEIVED < TRUNC(sysdate) + 1
```

Truncating a date sets the time to midnight, by default, so `TRUNC(sysdate)` is midnight this morning. For the range you get all records equal to or later than midnight this morning, and less than midnight tomorrow - which is what `TRUNC(sysdate) + 1` gives you, using normal Oracle datetime arithmetic.

You don't really want to convert it to a string with `TO_CHAR()`; you'd either have to convert all the column values to strings too (which is inefficient and prevents an index being used), or let the string be (implicitly) converted back to a date anyway. It's better to compare a column value with the same data type to reduce or avoid confusion.

Comment: In addition, notice and remember what Alex DIDN'T do. It could have been simpler (less typing) to compare TRUNC(DATE_RECEIVED) with TRUNC(SYSDATE). But that is not good practice. Whenever the wrapping of column values inside functions can be avoided, it should be avoided, even at the cost of longer code. This has to do with performance (ability to use an index on the DATE_RECEIVED column, which you may have since it seems this field is important in your queries).  +1 for always demonstrating good coding practices.

Comment: Thank you Mathguy, I will keep this in mind in the future.  I have plenty to learn about the proper habits of coding.